# Converting visualforce component to lightning component is not working properly autocomplete functionaliity?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, lightning-community

visualforce component :

```
<apex:component controller="autoCompleteController">
  <!-- JQuery Files -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js"/>
<apex:stylesheet value="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/themes/ui-smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
 <!-- Attributes Required For Component -->
  <apex:attribute name="objectname" description="The object name you want to look for."     type="String" required="true"/>
  <apex:attribute name="additionalfield" description="Any additional fields you'd like to search and include in the display."     type="String" required="false"/>
  <apex:attribute name="autocomplete_textbox" description="The ID for the Autocomplete List Textbox."     type="String" required="true"/>
  <style>
    .ui-autocomplete-loading { background: white url({!$Resource.circleIndicator}) right center no-repeat; }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
    j$(document).ready(function() {

        var sObjects;
        var queryTerm;

        j$(esc('{!autocomplete_textbox}')).autocomplete({
            minLength: 4,
            source: function(request, response) {
                        queryTerm = request.term;
                        autoCompleteController.findSObjects("{!objectname}", request.term, "{!additionalfield}", function(result, event){
                            if(event.type == 'exception') {
                                  alert(event.message);
                            } else {
                                 sObjects = result;
                                 response(sObjects);
                            }
                        });
                   },
            focus: function( event, ui ) {
                    j$(esc('{!autocomplete_textbox}')).val( ui.item.NicoPinFrace__c );
                    return false;
                    },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                        j$(esc('{!autocomplete_textbox}')).val( ui.item.NicoPinFrace__c );
                        j$(esc('{!autocomplete_textbox}_lkid')).val( ui.item.Id );
                        j$(esc('{!autocomplete_textbox}_lkold')).val( ui.item.NicoPinFrace__c );
                        return false;
                    },
         })
         .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            var entry = "<a>" + item.NicoPinFrace__c + "</a>";
            entry = entry.replace(queryTerm, "<b>" + queryTerm + "</b>");
            return j$( "<li></li>" )
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                .append( entry )
                .appendTo( ul );
        };
    });

    function esc(myid) {
           return '#' + myid.replace(/(:|\.)/g,'\\\\$1');
    }

  </script>
</apex:component>
```

Lightning component :

```
<aura:component controller="autoCompleteController">

    <!-- <ltng:require scripts="{!join(',',
    $Resource.jquery224 + '/jquery-2.2.4.min.js',
    $Resource.JqueryA + '/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js')}" 
      afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.doInit}" /> -->            
 <ltng:require scripts='/resource/jquery224.js' afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.doInit}"/>                  


  <aura:attribute name="objectname" description="The object name you want to look for." type="String" required="true" />
  <aura:attribute name="additionalfield" description="Any additional fields you'd like to search and include in the display." type="String" required="false"/>
  <aura:attribute name="autocomplete_textbox" description="The ID for the Autocomplete List Textbox." type="String" required="true"/>

</aura:component>
```

controller JS :

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
        j$(document).ready(function() {
        var sObjects;
        var queryTerm;

        j$(esc('{v.autocomplete_textbox}')).autocomplete({

            minLength: 4,
            source: function(request, response) {
                        queryTerm = request.term;
                        autoCompleteController.findSObjects("{v.objectname}", request.term, "{v.additionalfield}", function(result, event){
                            if(event.type == 'exception') {
                                  alert(event.message);
                            } else {
                                 sObjects = result;
                                 response(sObjects);
                            }
                        });
                   },
            focus: function( event, ui ) {
                    j$(esc('{v.autocomplete_textbox}')).val( ui.item.NicoPinFrace__c );
                    return false;
                    },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                        j$(esc('{v.autocomplete_textbox}')).val( ui.item.NicoPinFrace__c );
                        j$(esc('{v.autocomplete_textbox}_lkid')).val( ui.item.Id );
                        j$(esc('{v.autocomplete_textbox}_lkold')).val( ui.item.NicoPinFrace__c );
                        return false;
                    },
         })
         .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            var entry = "<a>" + item.NicoPinFrace__c + "</a>";
            entry = entry.replace(queryTerm, "<b>" + queryTerm + "</b>");
            return j$( "<li></li>" )
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                .append( entry )
                .appendTo( ul );
        };
    });

    function esc(myid) {
           return '#' + myid.replace(/(:|\.)/g,'\\\\$1');
     }
    }
})
```

apex controller

```
global class autoCompleteController {

    @RemoteAction
    @auraenabled
    global static SObject[] findSObjects(string obj, string qry, string addFields) {
        // more than one field can be passed in the addFields parameter
        // split it into an array for later use
        List<String> fieldList;
        if (addFields != null) fieldList = addFields.split(',');
       // check to see if the object passed is valid
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        Schema.SObjectType sot = gd.get(obj);
        if (sot == null) {
            // Object name not valid
            return null;
        }
        // create the filter text
        String filter = ' like \'%' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(qry) + '%\'';
        //begin building the dynamic soql query
        String soql = 'select id , Name ';
        // if an additional field was passed in add it to the soql
        if (fieldList != null) {
            for (String s : fieldList) {
                soql += ', ' + s;
            }
        }
        // add the object and filter by name to the soql
        soql += ' from ' + obj + ' where NicoPinFrace__c' + filter;
        // add the filter by additional fields to the soql
        if (fieldList != null) {
            for (String s : fieldList) {
                soql += ' or ' + s + filter;
            }
        }
        soql += ' order by NicoPinFrace__c limit 20';
        List<sObject> L = new List<sObject>();
        try {
            L = Database.query(soql);
        }
        catch (QueryException e) {
            return null;
        }
        return L;
   }
}
```

application component :

```
<aura:component >
<ui:inputtext  aura:id="memNam">
        <c:autoComplete2 autocomplete_textbox="{!$Component.memNam}" additionalfield="NicoPinFrace__c" objectname="NicoPinCodeFrance__c" />
</ui:inputtext> 
</aura:component>
```

I am converting my old visualforce component to lightning component

No specific error but I am not getting autocomplete output

can you someone help me regarding this :

Answer (score 2):

You still have some Visualforce syntax in your code that's tripping up your logic.

First, you have this:

```
    j$(esc('{v.autocomplete_textbox}')).autocomplete({
```

That's not going to work. Instead, you need something more like:

```
j$(component.find(component.get("v.autocomplete_textbox"))).autocomplete({
```

Or possibly even:

```
j$(esc(component.get("v.autocomplete_textbox"))).autocomplete({
```

However, either way, this may still get blocked by Locker Service (hint: it will only work on components in your own namespace, so no ui:inputText or lightning:input).

---

```
autoCompleteController.findSObjects("{v.objectname}", request.term, "{v.additionalfield}", function(result, event){
```

Remoting doesn't work in Lightning. You'll actually need something more like this:

```
var action = component.get("v.findSObjects");
action.setParams({ 
  obj: component.get("v.objectname"),
  qry: request.term,
  addFields: component.get("v.additionalfield")
});
action.setCallback(this, function(result) {
  if(component.getState() === "ERROR") {
    alert(result.getError()[0].message);
  } else {
    response(result.getReturnValue());
  }
});
$A.enqueueAction(action);
```

---

```
     .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
```

I'm not 100% on how you're going to translate this either, but it's probably going to involve an [aura:unescapedHtml](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:unescapedHtml) instead of native rendering.

---

Realistically, using jQuery in most Lightning Components makes everything way more complicated than it needs to be, and autocomplete is no exception.

You might want to look at [some example code](https://gist.github.com/peterknolle/ef17727d994332a8ef6b) that someone's already put out that demonstrates the proper way to go about this rather than try to "convert" from a Visualforce component. There's simply too much that can go wrong.